# [PUG]input(type="submit", value="Search") What is problem :(((

Tags: pug

```
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`
✅I'm working on https://localhost:4010
Error: /mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/src/views/index.pug:14:1
    12|                each country in countries
    13|                    option(value=country.code)= `${country.flag} ${country.name}`
  > 14|                 input(type="submit" value="Search" name="Search")
--------^

Inconsistent indentation. Expecting either 15 or 19 spaces/tabs.
    at makeError (/mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/node_modules/pug-error/index.js:34:13)
    at Lexer.error (/mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:62:15)
    at Lexer.indent (/mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1510:18)
    at Lexer.callLexerFunction (/mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1642:23)
    at Lexer.advance (/mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1683:12)
    at Lexer.callLexerFunction (/mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1642:23)
    at Lexer.getTokens (/mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1701:12)
    at lex (/mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:12:42)
    at Object.lex (/mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:104:9)
    at Function.loadString [as string] (/mnt/c/Users/nyang/flock-phone/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:53:24)
GET / 500 3902.067 ms - 1760
```

here is error and
**input(type="submit" value="Search")**
This is the problematic code.
what is problem.... :(
please help me :(
I re-installed the pug to fix it and fixed it for 30 minutes but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: It's on the error message, you have `Inconsistent indentation`. Remove 1 leading space before `input(type="submit" value="Search" name="Search")`.

Answer (score 1):

Pug relies on indentation style. Which means that it uses indentation to work out which tags are nested or a sibling. In your case the `input` tag is not nested properly. It should have the same indent as the `each` block.

```
each country in countries
    option(value=country.code)= `${country.flag} ${country.name}`
input(type="submit" value="Search" name="Search")
```